# How to create vertically centered html link button in a html div

Tags: html, css

I went through so many things about this. But still could not find any solution.
In every solution some restrictions are there. Can anyone provide a generalized and easiet css code for my problem to put a html link button vertically center inside an div?

As below in the image, the **create an account** button is at the middle of the div google header-bar :)
[image]

Comment: that is vertically centered, or am I missing something?

Comment: I think he's using the image as an example of what he means by "vertically centered".

Comment: if you know the height of each element it's pretty easy. you can add some padding or margins to the top to make it centered, or use `line-height:<container-height>`. try it out, and post some code when/if you get stuck.

Comment: google is using `margin-top` for the button and don't bother with `vertical-align` :) you can do same.

Comment: is there any generalized css framework where I can put any type of content like text or image or link in vertically centered manner inside any div without knowing hight or width of anything? Because everytime I am going to put something like this I have to calculate everytime for padding and dimensions of the elements :)

Comment: Please post the code you need help with.

Comment: @PerfectDark: You also need to add a negative top margin with half the height for that solution.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `line-height` the same like `height`, and also `display: inline-block`

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bslipek/j5yhuzoj/1/).

If you are using sass, then it is easy to write a mixin (in sass format):

```
=button($height: 40px)
  height: $height
  line-height: $height
```

Comment: This is better than other answers, as setting `line-height` is more natural and safer for a button, versus to set `height:100%` or `display:table-cell`

Answer (score 2):

You can combine display:table-cell and vertical-align:middle

```
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; height:50px; width:200px; background-color:silver;" >
  <a href="#link">
    <img src="" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the heights and margins appropriately.

[sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vx7h2/)

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">bbb</div>
    <div id="c">ccc</div>
</div>

#a {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100px;
}
#b {
    height: 80px;
    background-color:red;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#c {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 80px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is this trick I do a lot:

```
.valign-content:before {
   content : ''; 
   display : inline-block; 
   width : 0; height : 100%; 
   vertical-align : middle; 
}

.valign-content>* { 
   vertical-align : middle; 
   display : inline-block; 
}
```

heres the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/5g3Cz/

Does the trick for me...

Comment: @BartekS can you give a live example?

Comment: it is in your fiddle, Li1 text is not aligned with Li2 text.

Comment: @BartekS it is not the text that should be aligned, it is the `li`. If you set `height` to `auto` and just change the `font-size` you will see the result. You align the **wrapper** of the text, not the text alone. What is your case?

Comment: yes it works like that, you are right. but on the image at the top the text of all links all also aligned :) Maybe i just undarstend this question in different way :)

Comment: @BartekS If you want to `vertical-align` text you should go with @Michaël Hompus answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91016/discussion-between-bartek-s-and-xpy).